# Curb damages on 2015 Nissan Sentra

Tags: wheels

[image]
I was wondering if this needs immediate attention. It goes in next week (it’s a lease).

Answer (score 1):

as far as i can see the damage is only to the hubcap, just a tiny scratch on the rin ita insignificant . This is just a plastic wheel cover, it covers your rims to make them look a bit better and keep the dirt away from the hub, but that's all nothing to worry about, you can buy new cover for 10$ max.

Comment: As this is a Nissan original plastic wheel trim, it may well be more than the 10 bucks you suggest... Also, may not be available any more so needing a set...